# sqlalchemy using INTERSECT and UNNEST

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to translate a raw SQL to sqlalchemy core/orm but I'm having some difficulties. Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT UNNEST(MyTable.my_array_column) 
     INTERSECT 
     SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['VAL1', 'VAL2']::varchar[])) AS matched
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    my_array_column && ARRAY['VAL1', 'VAL2']::varchar[];
```

The following query, gives me a `FROM` clause which I don't need in my nested `SELECT`:

```
matched = select([func.unnest(MyTable.my_array_column)]).intersect(select([func.unnest('VAL1', 'VAL2')]))

# SELECT unnest(MyTable.my_array_colum) AS unnest_1 
# FROM MyTable INTERSECT SELECT unnest(%(unnest_3)s, %(unnest_4)s) AS unnest_2
```

How can I tell the `select` to not include the `FROM` clause? Note that `func.unnest()` only accepts a column. So I cannot use `func.unnest('my_array_column')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to a table of an enclosing query in a subquery is the process of [correlation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-subqueries), which SQLAlchemy attempts to do automatically. In this case, it doesn't quite work, I believe, because your `INTERSECT` query is a "selectable", not a scalar value, which SQLAlchemy attempts to put in the `FROM` list instead of the `SELECT` list.

The solution is twofold. We need to make SQLAlchemy put the `INTERSECT` query in the `SELECT` list by applying a `label`, and make it correlate `MyTable` correctly:

```
select([
    select([func.unnest(MyTable.my_array_column)]).correlate(MyTable)
    .intersect(select([func.unnest('VAL1', 'VAL2')]))
    .label("matched")
]).select_from(MyTable)

# SELECT (SELECT unnest("MyTable".my_array_column) AS unnest_1 INTERSECT SELECT unnest(%(unnest_3)s, %(unnest_4)s) AS unnest_2) AS matched 
# FROM "MyTable"
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.